# How to change the size of Plotly Toolbar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly

I am integrating a plotly graph in Shiny dashboard. And I decreased the size of plotly chart based on the dashboard layout.

However, the size of the toolbar was not decreased, so some information on the chart would be hided when I hover over the chart.

Below is the chart with this problem:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
p <- plot_ly(b1image, x = b1image$CNT, y = b1image$Label, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h', 
             marker = list(color = viridis::viridis_pal(option = "C", direction =1)(max(b1image$Label) - min(b1image$Label) + 5)))
p
```

I am wondering if there is a way to decrease the size this tool bar to make it not hiding chart information. Or, I can eliminate this tool bar, but want to have the option to get bar values by hovering over.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can indeed disable the toolbar, and bar values can be made available on hover by adding hoverinfo (they already show unformatted info by default 
          p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F) to remove the bar and the following inside add_trace to customize the info messages : 
 hoverinfo = "text",
                      text = ~paste ('<br>', 'bla bla : ',parametername, i.e. a column or such your plotting)) %>%

Comment: Thank you,it worked very well for me.

Comment: I posted is as answer so you can accept it if this answer is enough for your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed disable the toolbar,

and custom bar value messages can be made available on hover by adding 
hoverinfo (they already show unformatted info by default

`p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F)` 
to remove the bar.

And add the following inside `add_trace` to customize the info messages :

```
p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_trace(p, data = ..., x = ~columnname, y = ~columnname, 
     hoverinfo = "text", 
     text = ~paste ('<br>', 'bla bla : ',parametername, i.e. a column your plotting))

p
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, done:) I have another question regarding the axis on plotly chart, it is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55183157/r-plotly-has-x-axis-hidden. Would you mind to give me some insights on this? I appreciate it!